# Is there a way to track the memory used by my app to prevent the famous OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory, android-studio

As my app is using a lof of pictures, I get the famous issue of OutOfMemoryError on older devices.

Explanations: http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/

> According to Android Developers your device has at least 16MB of heap
>   space (T-Mobile G1) for storing your application data. But as Yekmer
>   said in  Yekmer’s Posterous , images are not stored in the heap space.
>   The space reserved for images in an Android application is  very
>   small, and having a big application using a lot of images, may easily
>   lead to the OutOfMemoryError.

**My question**

Having a lot of code, I would like to know if there is a tool in Android Studio that would help me to track the memory used by images and to know which steps of my code are increasinf the most the memory used.

**What I don't need**

I know how to get information like `ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` but I guess they won't be usefull, right?

**Some ideas**

I tried to understand the numbers given by "`adb shell dumpsys meminfo`", but I don't know if that would be a great start...

Comment: You can call [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) for the amount of memory (in MB) your app can use on the given device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MAT to diagnose memory leaks and other out-of-memory causes:

- [Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)
- [Google I|O conference video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)